# Put a customlistview inside fragment of tab

Tags: java, android, listview, tabs, fragment

So basically i need to know what the title say, i put my code:

the **ListAdapter.java**

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public ArrayList<Integer> quantità = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private String[] listViewItems, prezzi;
TypedArray images;

private Context context;
CustomButtonListener customButtonListener;

public ListAdapter(Context context, String[] listViewItems, TypedArray images, String[] prezzi) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listViewItems = listViewItems;
    this.images = images;
    this.prezzi=prezzi;

    for(int i =0; i< listViewItems.length; i++)
    {
        quantità.add(0);
        //quantity[i]=0;
    }
}

public void setCustomButtonListener(CustomButtonListener customButtonListner)
{
    this.customButtonListener = customButtonListner;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listViewItems.length;
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return listViewItems[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row;
    final ListViewHolder listViewHolder;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sis,parent,false);
        listViewHolder = new ListViewHolder();
        listViewHolder.tvFruitName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvFruitName);
        listViewHolder.ivFruit= (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ivFruit);
        listViewHolder.tvPrices = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvFruitPrice);
        listViewHolder.btnPlus = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.ib_addnew);
        listViewHolder.edTextQuantity = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editTextQuantity);
        listViewHolder.btnMinus = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.ib_remove);
        row.setTag(listViewHolder);
    }
    else
    {
        row=convertView;
        listViewHolder= (ListViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    listViewHolder.ivFruit.setImageResource(images.getResourceId(position, -1));
    listViewHolder.tvPrices.setText(prezzi[position]);

    try{

        listViewHolder.edTextQuantity.setText(quantità.get(position) + "");


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    listViewHolder.btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (customButtonListener != null) {
                customButtonListener.onButtonClickListener(position, listViewHolder.edTextQuantity, + 1);
                quantità.set(position,quantità.get(position) + 1);
            }

        }
    });

    listViewHolder.btnMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (customButtonListener != null) {
                customButtonListener.onButtonClickListener(position,listViewHolder.edTextQuantity,-1);
                if(quantità.get(position)>0)
                    quantità.set(position, quantità.get(position) - 1);
            }
        }
    });
    listViewHolder.tvFruitName.setText(listViewItems[position]);
    return row;
}

}
```

Then the **string.xml** where i put my array

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Ristorante</string>

<string-array name="fruitName">
    <item>Spaghetti allo scoglio</item>
    <item>Cherry</item>
    <item>Coconut</item>
    <item>Grape Fruit</item>
    <item>Lemon</item>
    <item>Strawberry</item>
    <item>Watermelon</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="fruitImages">
    <item>@mipmap/spaghettiscoglio</item>
    <item>@mipmap/caffeshakerato</item>
    <item>@mipmap/barbabietoleagrodolci</item>
    <item>@mipmap/barbadifrate</item>
    <item>@mipmap/bellinicocktail</item>
    <item>@mipmap/pennefume</item>
    <item>@mipmap/alettedipollo</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Price">
    <item>10 $</item>
    <item>12 $</item>
    <item>15 $</item>
    <item>24 $</item>
    <item>3 $</item>
    <item>50 $</item>
    <item>5 $</item>
</string-array>
```

and finally the **Tab1.java** where it gives me error on:
-   listAdapter = new ListAdapter(this,arrItems,images,prezzi);
-   listAdapter.setCustomButtonListener(this);

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

ListView listView;
ListAdapter listAdapter;
String[] arrItems,  prezzi;
TypedArray images;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1,container,false);

    arrItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fruitName);
    images = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.fruitImages);
    prezzi = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Price);
    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.customListView);
    listAdapter = new ListAdapter(this,arrItems,images,prezzi);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    listView.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);
    listAdapter.setCustomButtonListener(this);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onButtonClickListener(int position,EditText editText, int value) {
    /*
    View view = listView.getChildAt(position);*/
    int quantity = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
    quantity = quantity + 1 * value;
    if(quantity<0)
        quantity=0;
    editText.setText(quantity + "");
}
```

}

Comment: what error? plz post ur log

Comment: i don't know how to post log, but anyways i solved the first error that was;

Comment: listadapter = new ListAdapter(this, arrItems, images, prezzi), i changed this to getContext()

Comment: now i need to know how to solve the second error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listAdapter.setCustomButtonListener(this);` - `this` should point to `CustomButtonListener` object but it doesn't. If `CustomButtonListener` is interface then

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment implements CustomButtonListener
```

Here:

```
listAdapter = new ListAdapter(this,arrItems,images,prezzi);
```

should be

```
listAdapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(),arrItems,images,prezzi);
```

because you want to pass `Context`

Comment: it works!!! thank you a lot, i know that this is an easy error but i couldn't find it :/